# Использование вложенных компонентов в nuxt js

Tags: vue.js

Доброго времени суток!
Господа подскажите пожалуйста как использовать вложенные компоненты в nuxt js?

```
// ~/components/general/Page.vue

<template lang="pug">
  div(id="page" class="align-center")
</template>

// ~/components/general/Header.vue

<template lang="pug">
  header
    div(class="align-center align-middle")
      img(src="~/assets/general/header/logo.png")
</template>

// pages/index.vue

<template lang="pug">
 div
  page
   test
</template>

<script>
 import page from '~/components/general/Page.vue'
 import test from '~/components/general/Header.vue'

 export default {
  components: {
    page,
    test
  }
}
</script>
```

И соответственно такая конструкция не работает.
Что нужно сделать чтобы оно заработало?
Буду примного благодарен за пример

Comment: А для чего так вкладывать компоненты? в самом Vue любые вложения в компонент возможны через слоты

Comment: Если возможно, то опишите как.